# Parasoft SOAtest command line - import project

Tags: testing, command-line, automated-tests, parasoft

I am using the Parasoft SOAtest Linux version -soatestcli 9.8. How do I import the tests [.tst files] into my work space and run the tests.

I have tried soatestcli -import "tst-file-location" but it does not import the projects unless you copy over your entire workspace from parasoft GUI/eclipse.
What is the best way to import a test from the .tst file without manually copying over the eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some trail and error I figured what was missing. It was the .project file which should be included in the directory from where we are importing. 
Just include the .project file from your workspace and you will be good to import the files

Comment: To make it clear: you have to include .project file which defines Eclipse project where your tst was. It's important as you may have several projects in Eclipse workspace and if you use wrong one then import will fail. If you don't want to use command line, then use Import command from GUI (File>Import) and then you don't have to use .project file ( In GUI you can point only to tst  file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide project location instead of .tst location .. this is equivalent to import project in eclipse.

soatestcli -data “yourworkspace absolute path” -import “your project”
soatestcli -resource “your_project/yourtestfile.tst” -config “user://Example Configuration” -report “your report location”